# Read form data in Header in network tab

Tags: angularjs, payment-gateway

We are using AngularJs for integrating with PaymentGateway. Success or failure URLs are redirected from PG if it is success/Failure. But in success/failure URL they are posting data about transactions. we have the code to decrypt response message. But i need the code to retrieve the particular form data in value in url encoded.

Please refer below image. i need to fetch highlighted parameter value.

Can anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6kSl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Could u please try below code.Check is that coming in console.

```
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(headers); //for success
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(headers); //for failure/error
  });
```